# Error in URL.getFile()

Tags: java-7

I am trying to open a file from URL.

Object of URL is created with getResource() method of ClassLoader.
Output URL returned from getResource() method is =

```
file:/C:/users/
```

After using  URL.getFile() method which returns String as " /C:/users/ " it removes "**file:**" only not the "**/** " 
This / gives me a error in opening a file using new FileInputStream.
**Error : FileNotFoundException**

" / " in the starting of the filename causes the same problem in getting the path object.
Here , value of directory is retrieved from the URL.getResource().getFile()

Path Dest = Paths.get(Directory);

Error received is :
**java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 2: /C:/Users/**

is anyone face such issue ?

Answer (score 14):

Don't use `URL.getFile()`, it returns the "file" part of the URL, which is not the same as a file or path name of a file on disk. (It looks like it, but there are many ways in which there is a mismatch, as you have discovered.) Instead, call `URL.toURI()` and pass the resulting URI object to `Paths.get()`

That should work, as long as your URL points to a real file and not to a resource inside a jar file.

Example:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/some/resource/path");
Path dest = Paths.get(url.toURI());
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It works in second case, but for the first one while opening a file string with " /" in the start gives FilenotFound Exception.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your result path contains leading `/`.

Try:

```
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
Path path = Paths.get(loader.getResource(filename).toURI());
```