# java.nio.file.InvalidPathException with getPath

Tags: java

I am using this code

```
 String path =  getClass().getResource("Template.xls").getPath();
```

When I run it on my machine (windows), everything is good. I even did system.out.println on the get resource part and on the get path part and the results were:

file:/C:/Eclipse/Netbeans/SoftwareCom/build/classes/assets/Template.xls

/C:/Eclipse/Netbeans/SoftwareCom/build/classes/assets/Template.xls

However I am getting the following error reports from some users

```
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 4:
file:\C:\Software%20Com\SoftwareCom.exe!\assets\Template.xls
```

Iam not sure whats happening or why would it work for some and not others

Any pointers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To answer this question properly, it would be helpful to know what you want to do with the path information. To read the file, you don't need the path.
You could just call

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("Template.xls")
```

If you really want to know the path, you should call

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("Template.xls");
Path dest = Paths.get(url.toURI());
```

This might cause problems as you seem to pack your java files in a windows executable. See [Error in URL.getFile()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398699/error-in-url-getfile)

Edit for your comment:

As I wrote above, you don't need the path of the source to copy. You can use

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("Template.xls")
```

to get the content of the file and write the content to whereever you want to write it. The reason for failing is that the file in your second example is contained within an executable file:

```
 file:\C:\Software%20Com\SoftwareCom.exe
```

as can be seen from the path:

```
file:\C:\Software%20Com\SoftwareCom.exe!\assets\Template.xls
```

The exclamation mark indicates that the resource is within that file.
It works within Netbeans because there the resource is not packed in a jar, but rather is a separate file on the filesystem.
You should try to run the exe-version on your machine. It will most likely fail as well. If you want more information or help, please provide the complete code.

Comment: Absolutely. `String path =  getClass().getResource("Template.xls").getPath();` and `Paths.get(path);` would lead into the exception posted by the OP.

Comment: I needed the path info  because I perform copy from source to destination where source is the path. I can include thr copy code if needed.  The weird thing that this works on some machine and on others it does not. No solution to this?

Comment: I amended my answer. I think it fails if you run the exe version.

Comment: Perfect! You are AMAZING!

Answer (score 4):

I faced this same issue and go around it by using the good ol' File API

```
URL url = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("myScript.sh");
Path scriptPath = new File(url.getPath()).toPath();
```

And it worked!