# Why am I getting this InvalidPathException

Tags: java

Have some problem with this code. Namely I am getting the message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 2: [E:\Temp\564\324\123.txt]

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Path sourseFile = Paths.get("E:\\Temp");
    Path[] result = searchFile(sourseFile, "123");
    for (Path path : result) {
        System.out.println(path);
    }        
}

public static Path[] searchFile (Path path, String fileName)throws Exception{

    DirectoryStream<Path> dirStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(path);
    ArrayList<Path> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Path s : dirStream) {
        if (s.toFile().isDirectory()){
            temp.add(Paths.get(Arrays.toString(searchFile(s, fileName))));
        }
        else {
            if (s.toAbsolutePath().toString().contains(fileName)){
                temp.add(s.toAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
    return temp.toArray(Path[]::new);
}
```

**Full trace**

> Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 2: [E:\Temp\564\324\123.txt]
>           at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
>           at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
>           at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
>           at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:92)
>           at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:229)
>           at java.base/java.nio.file.Path.of(Path.java:147)
>           at java.base/java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:69)
>           at s09.Task1.searchFile(Task1.java:28)
>           at s09.Task1.searchFile(Task1.java:28)
>           at s09.Task1.main(Task1.java:13)

Comment: Maybe helpful [file-path-windows-format-to-java-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059383/file-path-windows-format-to-java-format)

Comment: Can you please provide a stack trace. Can you reduce the price to a couple of lines that fail the same way?

Comment: I agree. Try E:// and so on , and see what happens.

Comment: nope // not working at all. \\ works as it should in all other cases

Comment: replace yours `\\ ` for `/`

Comment: i replace \\ for / - nothing changes

Comment: how to resolve problem with ":"?

Comment: Do you have a "E" drive on the computer on which you are running the code you posted? Also, please show us the code for line 28 of file "Task1.java" (because according to the stack trace you posted, that line is throwing the `InvalidPathException`)

Comment: The problem is caused by invalid result from `URL.getPath()` method on Windows. This is elegant solution which helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54298796

Answer (score 5):

It appears that you're passing the string "[E:...]", including the surrounding square brackets added by Arrays.toString, to Paths.get. This then gets interpreted as a plain filename, in which the ":" character is indeed illegal.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the clue is in the exception message:

```
   Illegal char <:> at index 2: [E:\Temp\564\324\123.txt]
```

Notice that it is saying that the illegal character is at index 2.

Now Java uses zero-based indexing for strings and arrays and most other things<sup>1</sup>.  So if the `:` character is at offset `2`, then the `[` character must be the first character of the pathname; i.e. the actual "pathname" is being formed from `"[E:\Temp\564\324\123.txt]"` including the square brackets.

That is wrong.

So where is that coming from?

```
 temp.add(Paths.get(Arrays.toString(searchFile(s, fileName))));
```

What?

You are calling `Arrays.toString` on some array, and expecting that to be a valid pathname.  No way is that going to work.  Read the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[])) for `Arrays.toString()`.

For the record, here is a concise way to concatenate an array of strings to form a `Path`.

```
 String[] array = {"a", "b", "c"};
 Path p = Stream.of(array).map(Paths::get).reduce(Path::resolve).get();
 System.out.println(p);
```

---

<sup>1 - Including the offset in this exception message.  I checked the source code.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

**Added some code for replace [ ]**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
            Path sourseFile = Paths.get("E:\\Temp");
            Path[] result = searchFile(sourseFile, "123");
            for (Path path : result) {
                System.out.println(path);
            }
        }

        public static Path[] searchFile (Path path, String fileName)throws Exception{

            DirectoryStream<Path> dirStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(path);
            ArrayList<Path> temp = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Path s : dirStream) {
                if (s.toFile().isDirectory()){
                    **temp.add(Paths.get(Arrays.toString(searchFile(s, fileName)).replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]","")));**
                }
                else {
                    if (s.toAbsolutePath().toString().contains(fileName)){
                        temp.add(s.toAbsolutePath());
                    }
                }
            }
            return temp.toArray(Path[]::new);
        }
```