# When issuing scala from cmd the InvalidPathException occured

Tags: java, windows, scala

When I tried to issued scala from cmd, the following exception was reported.
I have tried different version of Java, from JDK20, JDK17 to this old JDK1.8, but the error persisted.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 2:  C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_341\lib\tools.jar
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
    at dotty.tools.dotc.core.MacroClassLoader$.$anonfun$1(MacroClassLoader.scala:25)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:250)
    at dotty.tools.dotc.core.MacroClassLoader$.makeMacroClassLoader(MacroClassLoader.scala:25)
    at dotty.tools.dotc.core.MacroClassLoader$.init(MacroClassLoader.scala:19)
    at dotty.tools.dotc.Driver.setup(Driver.scala:77)
    at dotty.tools.repl.ReplDriver.setupRootCtx(ReplDriver.scala:89)
    at dotty.tools.repl.ReplDriver.initialCtx(ReplDriver.scala:85)
    at dotty.tools.repl.ReplDriver.resetToInitial(ReplDriver.scala:111)
    at dotty.tools.repl.ReplDriver.<init>(ReplDriver.scala:126)
    at dotty.tools.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:7)
    at dotty.tools.MainGenericRunner$.run$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:193)
    at dotty.tools.MainGenericRunner$.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:270)
    at dotty.tools.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:281)
    at dotty.tools.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at coursier.bootstrap.launcher.a.a(Unknown Source)
    at coursier.bootstrap.launcher.Launcher.main(Unknown Source)
```

I have reinstalled Java and Scala, but cannot resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Illegal char <:> at index 2:  C:\Java\

If you pay attention to the error message, you'll see that `:` being at index 2 means the path that Java is trying to parse is actually starting with  `C:`, i.e. there's an extra character in position 0.

Check your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable or whatever place this path is defined and remove the extra first character.

---

Related to:

- [Java NIO file path issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834776/java-nio-file-path-issue)
- [Why am I getting this InvalidPathException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56736003/why-am-i-getting-this-invalidpathexception)